# How to use custom tiles in the OpenStreetMap?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, offline-caching

I am trying to create an offline map for my Android application. I'm hoping that the MapView I use will be able to have my tiles as an overlay. To do this, I have begun looking into using [Mapsforge](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/) and trying to figure out how to use my own maps. It seems that you need OpenStreetMap data, and I am not sure how to create this for the tiles I already have. OpenStreetMap's wiki talks about it [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Creating_your_own_tiles), but I haven't been able to decipher it.

To be clear, this is what I have so far:
Original map image.
Tiles for that map image.
Coordinates I want to use for the bound box.

I'm just not sure how to go from that, to a map which Mapsforge can use... Thanks for any help!

Edit: I also have a .kmz file for this custom map, but that can only be opened in Google Earth, not on an Android device, I think.